# Qt gui creation, widget resizing

Tags: qt, tabs, widget, docking

I am new to Qt development, even though I have years of MFC programming. I am trying to create a dockable widget and put some controls in the dock widget, a tab widget to be more precise. My problem is that the tab widget inside the dock widget doesn't resize along with the parent.

I'd like the tab widget to fill the entire area of the dock widget. Is it possible to manipulate some property in the same gui designer?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know If I understood your question, but try this: click anywhere the DockWidget (and outside the tab widget) and press the button idicated by the red arrow (it will be blue). Is that it?

This:

[image]

Becomes this:

[image]

Comment: @vinnythepoo: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You don't appear to ever accept an answer, even if it answers your question. If nothing else, you are awarded +2 reputation, when you do.